# Android OnCreate input bundle always null

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-context, android-savedstate

I am undertaking project but I have been having some issues with activities and saving state. So I have gone back to basics to try and understand what I was missing. However, even with a very simple set up I am having the same issues.

So I started with an empty project and placed 2 textViews and 1 button on the activity_main.xml and 1 button on the activity_2.xml. The user will enter some text in a text box, press the button to advance to the Activity2 Activity and then press the button (in the Activity2 layout) to return back to the MainActivity.

My hope is that the text entered into the text box has been saved by the overriden onSaveInstanceState method and then the bundle argument in the OnCreate will hold this value. However, when MainActivity is hit, the bundle is alywas null despite onSaveInstanceState being called when button to start Activity2 is pressed.

Am I missing something? The onSaveInstanceState method is definitely initiated and savedInstanceState is populated within it, so why when the MainActivity is started again and onCreate is called is the Bundle savedInstanceState null? Is it the way I am setting up starting other Activities?

Thanks for your help!

For reference, here is my setup:

My MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button forwardButton;
    TextView editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        forwardButton = findViewById(R.id.buttonForward);
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        forwardButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                Intent activity2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Activity2.class);
                startActivity(activity2);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String textToSave = editText.getText().toString();
        savedInstanceState.putString("editText",textToSave);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }
}``
```

My Activity2 class:

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button goBack;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_2);

        goBack = findViewById(R.id.goBack);
        goBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                Intent activity2 = new Intent(Activity2.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(activity2);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonForward"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:text="Forward"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="96dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="102dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="268dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="Enter"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

activity_2.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Activity2">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/goBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="162dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="232dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="162dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="76dp"
        android:text="Go back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: "so why when the MainActivity is started again and onCreate is called is the Bundle savedInstanceState null?" -- because it is a completely different activity instance. Other than being of the same class, it is completely unrelated to your original instance, because you started a second instance. If you want to have `Activity2` return to your existing instance of `MainActivity`, call `finish()` in your `onClick()` method, not `startActivity()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Okay cool thanks - that makes sense. So say I want to add a third activity that when finished goes back to the second activity, how does the finish() method know which activity to then go back to - is it the one where the activity was started? And secondly, say the app is being loaded from scratch and it needs the data from the last session - do I need to serialise the data from the previous session on the onDestroy() and then reload on the first onCreate in the MainActivity?

Comment: Also, does this mean that onCreate and the input bundle argument are not invoked or useful at all between Activity changes? i.e. they are only used when things like orientation changes occur or when the app is completely restarted from scratch and data needs to be loaded from storage? In the later case the input bundle argument will still be null correct?

Comment: "how does the finish() method know which activity to then go back to - is it the one where the activity was started?" -- control returns to whatever activity preceded it on the back stack. "do I need to serialise the data from the previous session on the onDestroy() and then reload on the first onCreate in the MainActivity?" -- you need to save the data someplace. Usually, you do that when the data changes, as `onDestroy()` is not guaranteed to be called.

Comment: "they are only used when things like orientation changes occur" -- that is the primary scenario. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#saras) and books on Android app development for more.

Comment: Okay so correct me if I am wrong, the Activity lifecycle is obviously useful but falls down whenever we have which needs to span sessions. The lifecycle temporarily protects data and state depending on specific scenarios but between launching the app at different occasions, data needs to be persisted in some other way.

Comment: If you could confirm something else for me related to the comments in the post below... If onSavedInstanceState is called on MainActivity but onRestoreInstanceState or onCreate are not called when MainActivity is re-entered, how is the data/state maintained? I know that onPause and onStop are called when Activity2 is started and onStart and onResume are called when MainActivity is entered again but how does it know the state of how it was left?

Comment: "but between launching the app at different occasions, data needs to be persisted in some other way" -- correct. This is no different than how most software has been developed for the past 50 years or so. "how does it know the state of how it was left?" -- it "knows" the state because the state did not go anywhere. It is the same `MainActivty` object as before, with the same widgets as before, and those widgets have the same content as before.

Comment: Okay brilliant thanks for all of your answers! One last thing to complete the picture - if I am using finish() to go from Activity2 back to MainActivity, how do I then re-open this same Activity2 activity with the same state? Is there a method which saves the state of Activity2 and returns to MainActivity, meaning when the button in MainActivity is pressed again, the same Activity2 will reopen and the state will be conserved?

Comment: "how do I then re-open this same Activity2 activity with the same state?" -- you would need to save that state somewhere and use it. This scenario is not much different than "how do we re-open this same Activity2 activity with the same state three weeks from now?". You could use SQLite, or `SharedPreferences`, or some other sort of file, or a server. For your specific scenario, some in-app caching can boost performance, assuming both instances of Activity2 are operating off of the same data. This sort of stuff is covered in books and courses on Android app development.

Comment: Currently, when I re-enter Activity2 for the second time, there is no saved state. Unless there is a method as mentioned in my last comment above, if finish() is used the only way to keep the data is to save it away on disk right?

Comment: "Currently, when I re-enter Activity2 for the second time, there is no saved state" -- correct. "f finish() is used the only way to keep the data is to save it away on disk right?" -- usually, you save the data when the data changes. However, the details will depend a lot on what Activity2 is, what the data is, where you are storing the data, and what the expected usage of your app is.

Answer (score 0):

**In your `Activity2`**

```
    goBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Activity2.this.finish();
        }
    });
```

**And get your saved instance in `MainActivity` from `onRestoreInstanceState`**

```
//this will trigger when the same instance of activity is restored
//by the back press that finishes the Activity2
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  String data = savedInstanceState.getString("editText");

}
```

Comment: Okay so this works in terms of the data saved in onSavedInstanceState seems to be reloaded back into the MainActivity after Activity2.this.finish();. However, debugging shows that onRestoreInstanceState is not invoked in the MainActivity when it is re-entered. Similarly onCreate() is not invoked - I assume as onDestroy() was not before it moved to Activity2.

Comment: `onSavedInstanceState ` will be called when your activity is visible again, onCreate is only called when you create the activity like calling it via intent directly or when you rotate the device while still on the activity.

Comment: The fact that your data is restored when you finish() means that `onSavedInstanceState ` is triggered.

Comment: I know onSavedInstanceState is called when I leave my MainActivity. However, if onCreate is not called when the activity is re-entered and I know onRestoreInstanceState is not called due to debugging - how it the state of MainActivity persisted until the next time it is made active?

Comment: Also, why when I call Activity2.this.finish();, doesn't the onSavedInstanceState get called in the Activity2 class? Surely this calls onStop and onDestroy which then requires onSavedInstanceState to be called?

Comment: Because you didn't save the data in the Activity 2 instance. `onSavedInstanceState` is triggered after `onStart()` means when the activity is created and when the activity is visible again like in your case.

Comment: When you saved data to first activity and went to the second activity, the first activity instance is still alive. So when you call finish() in second activity the first activity's `onStart()` gets triggered and then `onSavedInstanceState ` and you restore the data.